# Conditinal ranking of data from lists nested in dictionarys

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, conditional-statements

I got started learning python with the cs50x course and got to my first own project, a discordbot providing a map choise for our cs:go squad. so far i got the datacollection done and now have a dictionary filled with a dictionary for each map, filled with lists for various stats:

```
mapdata = [
    ('de_inferno', {'winrate': [54, 52, 55, 29, 51], 'matches': [52, 56, 22, 21, 71], 'wins': [28, 29, 12, 6, 36], 'twins': [26, 26, 11, 8, 36], 'ctwins': [29, 32, 12, 11, 38], 'total': [5, 222, 50, 48, 54]}),
    ('de_nuke', {'winrate': [60, 65, 65, 71, 54], 'matches': [30, 34, 20, 14, 35], 'wins': [18, 22, 13, 10, 19], 'twins': [14, 16, 10, 8, 15], 'ctwins': [18, 21, 13, 9, 21], 'total': [5, 133, 61, 47, 61]}),
    ('de_dust2', {'winrate': [47, 41, 36, 33, 50], 'matches': [30, 34, 11, 9, 32], 'wins': [14, 14, 4, 3, 16], 'twins': [14, 15, 4, 4, 17], 'ctwins': [16, 17, 6, 5, 17], 'total': [5, 116, 43, 46, 52]}),
    ('de_overpass', {'winrate': [54, 64, 14, 82, 30], 'matches': [26, 25, 7, 11, 27], 'wins': [14, 16, 1, 9, 8], 'twins': [12, 11, 3, 6, 10], 'ctwins': [15, 16, 3, 6, 15], 'total': [5, 96, 50, 43, 57]}),
    ('de_vertigo', {'winrate': [82, 63, 75, 75, 55], 'matches': [11, 8, 4, 4, 11], 'wins': [9, 5, 3, 3, 6], 'twins': [5, 4, 2, 3, 5], 'ctwins': [7, 4, 3, 2, 6], 'total': [5, 38, 68, 50, 57]}),
    ('de_mirage', {'winrate': [60, 50, 0, 33, 63], 'matches': [5, 2, 1, 3, 8], 'wins': [3, 1, 0, 1, 5], 'twins': [2, 0, 0, 1, 3], 'ctwins': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6], 'total': [5, 19, 52, 31, 63]}),
    ('de_ancient', {'winrate': [33, 50, 43], 'matches': [3, 2, 7], 'wins': [1, 1, 3], 'twins': [1, 1, 2], 'ctwins': [1, 1, 4], 'total': [3, 12, 41, 33, 50]}),
    ('de_anubis', {'winrate': [0, 50, 50, 67], 'matches': [3, 4, 2, 6], 'wins': [0, 2, 1, 4], 'twins': [2, 2, 1, 3], 'ctwins': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'total': [4, 15, 46, 53, 46]}),
    ('de_cache', {'winrate': [0, 0, 38], 'matches': [2, 2, 8], 'wins': [0, 0, 3], 'twins': [0, 1, 4], 'ctwins': [1, 1, 4], 'total': [3, 12, 25, 41, 50]}),
    ('de_tuscan', {'winrate': [100], 'matches': [1], 'wins': [1], 'twins': [1], 'ctwins': [0], 'total': [1, 1, 100, 100, 0]}),
    ('de_train', {'winrate': [33], 'matches': [3], 'wins': [1], 'twins': [1], 'ctwins': [2], 'total': [1, 3, 33, 33, 66]})
]
```

the last list in each dict contains the first part of the analysis, providing Players that played the map, Total playcount, Winrate overall, Winrate t and Winrate ct. getting my reults out of that dict working so far, but i would like to add a condition to cut out results with "Players that played the map" <= 3

```
sortedlist = sorted(mapdata, key=lambda x: (mapdata[x]["total"][2]), reverse=True)
```

provides me with the correct order of maps, sorted by the winrate in the total list.
i could now seach for the correspondig values for each map and combine the 2 lists, but im pretty sure the sorted function can help me out there aswell.
i cant really wrap my head around the key=lambda x: part. as far as i understand it, mapdata[x] gets sorted by the ranking of (mapdata[x]["total"][2]). how to output these values aswell?

on the other hand, i would like to only accept maps in the ranking, which where played by the majority of players, so (mapdata[x]["total"][0]) shoulb be 4 or greater (this number would change if there are not 5 players present at a time). this could be achieved by cloning and stripping the dict beforehand, but i feel like there could be a way to do this in the sorted function aswell.

Thanks for helping me out!
as addition: i'm open for an other datastructure, i did allready switch it up from a csv to dict, and i' still nor sure if a dictionary for each map is the way to go (but it helped me with the datacollection and will be usefull for further analysis)

Comment: So given your starting list, you want map data (map name only?) for maps that have a `mapdata[x]["total"][0] >= 4` ordered by `mapdata[x]["total"][2]`?

Comment: yes! best case would be mapname:value of [2] as output, but i can lookup 2 later asswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at `filtered` used in tandem with `sorted`.  The first to get just the maps of interest and the second to put them in a nice order.

After that you can create a lookup dictionary or if you just wanted a list of tuples you could do that as well...

```py
mapdata = [
    ('de_inferno', {'winrate': [54, 52, 55, 29, 51], 'matches': [52, 56, 22, 21, 71], 'wins': [28, 29, 12, 6, 36], 'twins': [26, 26, 11, 8, 36], 'ctwins': [29, 32, 12, 11, 38], 'total': [5, 222, 50, 48, 54]}),
    ('de_nuke', {'winrate': [60, 65, 65, 71, 54], 'matches': [30, 34, 20, 14, 35], 'wins': [18, 22, 13, 10, 19], 'twins': [14, 16, 10, 8, 15], 'ctwins': [18, 21, 13, 9, 21], 'total': [5, 133, 61, 47, 61]}),
    ('de_dust2', {'winrate': [47, 41, 36, 33, 50], 'matches': [30, 34, 11, 9, 32], 'wins': [14, 14, 4, 3, 16], 'twins': [14, 15, 4, 4, 17], 'ctwins': [16, 17, 6, 5, 17], 'total': [5, 116, 43, 46, 52]}),
    ('de_overpass', {'winrate': [54, 64, 14, 82, 30], 'matches': [26, 25, 7, 11, 27], 'wins': [14, 16, 1, 9, 8], 'twins': [12, 11, 3, 6, 10], 'ctwins': [15, 16, 3, 6, 15], 'total': [5, 96, 50, 43, 57]}),
    ('de_vertigo', {'winrate': [82, 63, 75, 75, 55], 'matches': [11, 8, 4, 4, 11], 'wins': [9, 5, 3, 3, 6], 'twins': [5, 4, 2, 3, 5], 'ctwins': [7, 4, 3, 2, 6], 'total': [5, 38, 68, 50, 57]}),
    ('de_mirage', {'winrate': [60, 50, 0, 33, 63], 'matches': [5, 2, 1, 3, 8], 'wins': [3, 1, 0, 1, 5], 'twins': [2, 0, 0, 1, 3], 'ctwins': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6], 'total': [5, 19, 52, 31, 63]}),
    ('de_ancient', {'winrate': [33, 50, 43], 'matches': [3, 2, 7], 'wins': [1, 1, 3], 'twins': [1, 1, 2], 'ctwins': [1, 1, 4], 'total': [3, 12, 41, 33, 50]}),
    ('de_anubis', {'winrate': [0, 50, 50, 67], 'matches': [3, 4, 2, 6], 'wins': [0, 2, 1, 4], 'twins': [2, 2, 1, 3], 'ctwins': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'total': [4, 15, 46, 53, 46]}),
    ('de_cache', {'winrate': [0, 0, 38], 'matches': [2, 2, 8], 'wins': [0, 0, 3], 'twins': [0, 1, 4], 'ctwins': [1, 1, 4], 'total': [3, 12, 25, 41, 50]}),
    ('de_tuscan', {'winrate': [100], 'matches': [1], 'wins': [1], 'twins': [1], 'ctwins': [0], 'total': [1, 1, 100, 100, 0]}),
    ('de_train', {'winrate': [33], 'matches': [3], 'wins': [1], 'twins': [1], 'ctwins': [2], 'total': [1, 3, 33, 33, 66]})
]

##----------------------------
## Only maps played by 4 or more players
##----------------------------
foo = filter(lambda item: item[1]["total"][0] >= 4, mapdata)
##----------------------------

##----------------------------
## Fillter maps from above orderd by ranking
##----------------------------
bar = sorted(foo, key=lambda item: item[1]["total"][2], reverse=True)
##----------------------------

##----------------------------
## Reshape your ordered data into collection of tuples
##----------------------------
baz = map(lambda item: (item[0], item[1]["total"][2]), bar)
baz = list(baz) # map returns an iterator that we would consume to do the first print so capture it as a list here
##----------------------------

##----------------------------
## Printing your data as a list or dictionary
##----------------------------
print("\nUsing filter/sorted/map:")
print(f"\tAs a list (of tuples): { baz } ")
print(f"\tAs a dictionary: { dict(baz) } ")
##----------------------------

##----------------------------
## Finally, if you like comprehensions, you could do this
## for the same effect. Note that this sorts then filters where in
## the first case we filtered then sorted.
##----------------------------
baz = [
    (item[0], item[1]["total"][2])
    for item
    in sorted(mapdata, key=lambda item: item[1]["total"][2], reverse=True)
    if item[1]["total"][0] >= 4
]
print("\nUsing comprehension:")
print(f"\tAs a list (of tuples): { list(baz) } ")
print(f"\tAs a dictionary: { dict(baz) } ")
##----------------------------
```

This should give you:

```
Using filter/sorted/map:
        As a list (of tuples): [('de_vertigo', 68), ('de_nuke', 61), ('de_mirage', 52), ('de_inferno', 50), ('de_overpass', 50), ('de_anubis', 46), ('de_dust2', 43)]
        As a dictionary: {'de_vertigo': 68, 'de_nuke': 61, 'de_mirage': 52, 'de_inferno': 50, 'de_overpass': 50, 'de_anubis': 46, 'de_dust2': 43}

Using comprehension:
        As a list (of tuples): [('de_vertigo', 68), ('de_nuke', 61), ('de_mirage', 52), ('de_inferno', 50), ('de_overpass', 50), ('de_anubis', 46), ('de_dust2', 43)]
        As a dictionary: {'de_vertigo': 68, 'de_nuke': 61, 'de_mirage': 52, 'de_inferno': 50, 'de_overpass': 50, 'de_anubis': 46, 'de_dust2': 43}
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for your effort!
i tried the filter followed up with sorted, but raises a type-error for
`code`
    foo = filter(lambda item: item[1]['total'][0] >= 4, mapdata)
                              ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
(marked is the "total")
`code`

also i dont really understand how mapdata["name"] turns into item[1], aswell as why the source for filter/sorted is placed after/infront of the parameters, but im checking the documentation right now.
also, is there a proper editor for commenting? :D

Comment: @Sven If it makes you more comfortable, `foo = list(filter(lambda item: item[1]["total"][0] >= 4, mapdata))` is equivalent to `foo = [item for item in mapdata if item[1]['total'] >= 4]`

Comment: If you are getting a type error, can you verify that your data looks like your example.  Perhaps some of the data is text rather than numbers.

Comment: @Steff yep, that makes it much clearer for me!
at JonSG type error was on my side. copied the mapdata out of the terminal, but i had it present as a dict in my code. just converted it into an list and it works fine